# Which is this series

Tags: combinatorics

When
    `m = 2, series is 1,2,3,4,5..`

```
m = 3 : 1,3,6,10,15..

m = 4 : 1,4,10,20,35..

m = 5 : 1,5,15,35,70..

m = 6 : 1,6,21,56,126..
```

So given value of m, can I find the entire series ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks rather like Pascal's triangle, especially if for  $m=1$ the sequence is $1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$

Comment: For given $m$, the sequence is $\binom{m+k-1}{k}$ with $k$ start from $0$. The corresponding OGF is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+k-1}{k} z^k = \frac{1}{(1-z)^m} $.

Answer (score 2):

I guess:

$\displaystyle
\left \{
  1, m, \frac{m(m+1)}{2}, \frac{m(m+1)(m+1)}{6} , \ldots , \binom{m+k-2}{k-1}
 \right \}
=\left \{ \binom{m+k-2}{k-1} \right \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$

Comment: Here, k is kth term of the series right? And this is not converging series..

Comment: K can not start from 0 right?

Comment: Looks fine now.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

These are obviously oblique rows in Pascal's triangle,

$$\binom{m-1+n}{n}=\frac{(m-1+n)!}{(m-1)!n!}=\frac{(m-1+n)(m-2+n)\cdots(n+1)}{(m-1)!}.$$

The sequence for $m$ is the prefix sum of the sequence for $m-1$.

For example, for $m=4$,

$$\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3}{1\cdot2\cdot3},\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4}{1\cdot2\cdot3},\frac{3\cdot4\cdot5}{1\cdot2\cdot3},\frac{4\cdot5\cdot6}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\cdots$$

You can compute the sequences efficiently by recurrence,

$$S_{m,n}=S_{m,n-1}\frac{m-1+n}{n}.$$

For $m=4$,

$$1,1\cdot\frac41=4,4\cdot\frac52=10,10\cdot\frac63=20\cdots$$